Is it true that Buddhism declined in India due to the Advent of Advaita Vedanta of Adi shankaracharya?
It seems to be a widely held belief held by Hindu scriptures and scholars that The God Shiva incarnated as Adi Shankaracharya in order to stop buddhism.

“In this regard, it is stated in the Padma Purana that Lord Siva
appeared as a brahmana in the age of Kali to preach the Mayavada
philosophy, which is nothing but a type of Buddhist philosophy. It is
stated in Padma Purana: Lord Siva, speaking to Parvati-devi,
foretold that he would spread the Mayavada philosophy in the guise of
a sannyasi brahmana just to eradicate Buddhist philosophy. This
sannyasi was Sripada Sankaracarya. In order to overcome the effects of
Buddhist philosophy and spread Vedanta philosophy, Sripada
Sankaracarya had to make some compromise with the Buddhist philosophy,
and as such he preached the philosophy of monism, for it was required
at that time. Otherwise there was no need for his preaching Mayavada
philosophy. At the present moment there is no need for Mayavada
philosophy or Buddhist philosophy, and Lord Caitanya rejected both of
them. This Krishna consciousness movement is spreading the philosophy
of Lord Caitanya and rejecting the philosophy of both classes of
Mayavadi. Strictly speaking, both Buddhist philosophy and Sankara’s
philosophy are but different types of Mayavada dealing on the platform
of material existence. Neither of these philosophies has spiritual
significance. There is spiritual significance only after one accepts
the philosophy of Bhagavad-gita, which culminates in surrendering unto
the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

~  Swami Bhaktivedanta Prabhupada on Srimad Bhagavatam 4.24.17

The exact word used in Sanskrit is nāstika, which refers to one who
does not believe in the Vedas but manufactures some concocted system
of religion. Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu has said that the followers of
the Buddhist system of religion are nāstikas. In order to establish
his doctrine of nonviolence, Lord Buddha flatly refused to believe in
the Vedas, and thus, later on, Śaṅkarācārya stopped this system of
religion in India and forced it to go outside India.

~ Swami Bhaktivedanta Prabhupada on Srimad Bhagavatam 4.2.30

Now my question is NOT about what buddhists think about the validity of Advaita or Whether Shankara was an incarnation.
What I am more interested in knowing is that was it really Vedanta / Adi shankara's philosophy that was the main factor responsible for the decline of Buddhism in India? What do Buddhist experts themselves opine on the matter?

Edit:- It would appear the question has been flagged as duplicate. I have seen the linked question and it does not specifically address the question since none of the answers have discussed how much role Adi shankara played in the decline of buddhism in india. I would request the question to be re-opened as I am skeptical of the notion that Adi shankara philosophically defeating buddhists was the major reason behind the decline of buddhism in India and I would like to see If any evidence can be found to the contrary.

This question seems to be a duplicate of an existing question. Please see the linked question to determine if answers to that question answers your question too.

@ruben2020 I have seen the linked question and it does not specifically address the question since none of the answers have discussed how much role Adi shankara played in the decline of buddhism in india. I would request the question to be re-opened as I am skeptical of the notion that Adi shankara philosophically defeating buddhists was the major reason behind the decline of buddhism in India and I would like to see If any evidence can be found to the contrary.

Much of your post is plain folklore, unverifiable and undebatable. Then, you claimed that Adi Shankara's philosophy is not the cause of Buddhism decline in India when many in this forum know little of this philosophy in the 1st place. It's like you found a bunch of cats then asked, "Can any of you bark?". Maybe you might want to rethink the post? Hope this comment helps.

@Desmon I assumed most people in the community would know about Advaita considering it had been considered one of the most prolific philosophical opponents of buddhism and there has been a  history of philosophical refutation and counter refutation between the philosophies.

Reopened based on the edit

@SupremeVoid I admit I know little of Adaita Vedanta. It appeared to grew in fame only centuries after the author's death. Most Buddhist texts were already transmitted to various countries much earlier, many even before Shankara's time. E.g. Buddhism was already in China in the Han dynasty.

@Desmon Yes No one really denies the antiquity of Buddhism over Shankaran Vedanta. However there is a widespread narrative that buddhism declining in india the consequence of getting philosophically 'debunked' by the vedantists. That notion needed to be addressed.

Just pointing that it seems all the traditional Buddhist texts that survived had no mentioned of Adaita Vedanta, let alone critics on it. Likewise, many Buddhists would not had read about it in the traditional texts. Why may I ask do you need to address the notion?

I have already commented on this in this answer.
There are several Hindu rhetorics and polemics against Buddhism and Jainism.
One is that Adi Shankara defeated Buddhism using Advaita Vedanta, which the Vaishnava Dvaitins say was Lord Shiva's false teachings to defeat Buddhism. This is based on the Padma Purana text.
The Vaishnava Dvaitins also say that the Buddha is Lord Vishnu's incarnation to make the immoral atheists practise moral values, while remaining as atheists and serving Buddha (who is God in disguise). They also say Buddha corrected those practising Vedas wrongly by ending animal sacrifices. This is based on the Bhagavata Purana text.
The other type of polemics is the creation of new puranas and Brahmasutras, and then backdating and claiming they came before Buddhism. The Bhagavata Purana was written much later to make Buddha into the incarnation of Vishnu. The Brahmasutras were written much later to refute Buddhism and Jainism, as well as other philosophical schools that its author did not like. All the dates by professional academic scholars can be found in Wikipedia.

When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
the Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
Buddha and will preach on subreligious principles.
Bhagavata Purana 2.7.37

The next type of polemics is writing of yet other puranas like Kalki Purana and Agni Purana to claim Kalki will come and destroy Buddhism and Jainism. You can read the translation of the Kalki Purana yourself to verify this.
In my opinion, these stories don't make sense. Why would Lord Vishnu come as Buddha to deceive people by creating the false teachings of Buddhism, then Lord Shiva came as Adi Shankara to deceive people by creating the false teachings of Advaita Vedanta to counter Buddhism, and then finally Lord Vishnu will come again as Kalki to destroy Buddhism, which he himself preached as Buddha.
So, what's the truth?
The first reason why Buddhism declined in the Indian subcontinent is hard assimilation by foreign invaders. That's what happened in Afghanistan, Pakistan and Bangladesh which previously had many Buddhists.
The founders of Advaita Vedanta, Gaudapada and Adi Shankara, came 1200 years after the Buddha, 500 years after Nagarjuna (founder of Madhyamaka aka Sunyavada) and 300 years after Asanga and Vasubandhu (founders of Yogacara aka Vijnanavada). They did not defeat Buddhism using Advaita. Rather, they borrowed ideas from Buddhist schools and combined them with the Upanishadic teachings to create Advaita Vedanta. Even in his time, Adi Shankara was accused of being a crypto-Buddhist by the Dvaitins.
By introducing Advaita, Adi Shankara softly assimilated Buddhist philosophy into Hinduism, confusing Buddhists and Hindus into thinking that Advaita Vedanta and Mahayana Buddhism teach the same thing in different terms when they do not. Even today, Advaitins like to claim that the Shunyata (Emptiness) of Madhyamaka Buddhism and Nirguna Brahman (Formless Attributeless God) of Advaita Vedanta is the same when it is not. This is the second reason why Buddhism declined in India.
From Wikipedia's Buddhist influences on Advaita Vedanta, we find the quote of Professor S.N. Dasgupta:

Shankara and his followers borrowed much of their dialectic form of
criticism from the Buddhists. His Brahman was very much like the sunya
of Nagarjuna [...] The debts of Shankara to the self-luminosity of the
Vijnanavada Buddhism can hardly be overestimated. There seems to be
much truth in the accusations against Shankara by Vijnana Bhiksu and
others that he was a hidden Buddhist himself. I am led to think that
Shankara's philosophy is largely a compound of Vijnanavada and
Sunyavada Buddhism with the Upanisad notion of the permanence of self
superadded.

The Dvaitins liked neither Buddhism nor Advaita. So, they made Buddha into the incarnation of Vishnu and claimed he gave false teachings for some special reason. This is another way to softly assimilate Buddhism. This is the third reason why Buddhism declined in India, that is by turning Buddha into a Hindu divine incarnation.
In addition to this, Hindu scholars like to claim all these newer scriptures like Bhagavata Purana, Agni Purana, Kalki Purana, Padma Purana, Brahmasutras were written long before the coming of the Buddha, to claim this was foretold. Professional academicians have debunked this. This is the scriptural way to support the two methods of soft assimilation above.
But Buddhism was in no way defeated by Adi Shankara or the foreign invaders. It flourished in Sri Lanka, Burma, Thailand, Tibet, and other East Asian countries.
This is summarized in the quote of Professor Peter Harvey in Wikipedia's Decline of Buddhism in the Indian subcontinent:

Between the alien, with their doctrinal justification of "holy war" to
spread the faith, and Hindus, closely identified with Indian culture
and with a more entrenched social dimension, the Buddhists were
squeezed out of existence. Lay Buddhists were left with a folk form of
Buddhism, and gradually merged into Hinduism, or converted to Islam.
Buddhism, therefore, died out in all but the fringes of its homeland,
though it had long since spread beyond it.


+1 for the well researched details.

the Australian monk named Sujato seems to believe the new puranas and Brahmasutras, and then backdating and claiming they came before Buddhism

This answer is a bit confusing about the foreign invaders. Hinduism & Jainism survived the foreign invaders. In fact, the foreign invaders invited the Jains for discussion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism#Medieval). Buddhism obviously declined due to its own crimes against itself. Today, we can simply for ourselves observe the decline of every Buddhist chatsite; such as the garbage posted daily on DW or myriad reinventions of Buddhism by the myriad wannabe scholars on SC. The translations by Sujato appear to be deliberate corruptions. Buddhism destroys itself.
